# Match comment, but not inside a string

Tags: regex, perl

I’d like to match comments in Perl.

- double or single quotes strings are not strings if inside comments
- `#`s inside strings are not comments

Here is an example, each string and comments needs to be captured and highlighted later.

```
# this is a comment, should be matched.
# # "I am not a string" . 'because I am inside a comment'
my $string = " #I am not a comment, because I am quoted";
my $another_string = "I am a multiline string with # on
                      each line #, have fun!";
my $descap_string = "I am a \ escaped \" \"string"; # and some comments;
my $sescap_string = 'I am a \ escaped \' \'string'; # and some comments;
my $empty_d ="";
my $empty_s ='';
```

I tried few things, but could not work out a solution to cover all the situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you simply need to rely on the ordered nature of the code.  Basically, come up with your regular expressions for quotes and comments, and put them in an or'd list in a single regex.

The following is a stub of what I'm talking about:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dquo_re = qr{...};
my $squo_re = qr{...};
my $comment_re = qr{...};

my $src = do {local $/; <DATA>};

while ($src =~ /($dquo_re)|($squo_re)|($comment_re)/g) {
    if (defined $1) {
        print "Double quote found: $1\n";
    } elsif (defined $2) {
        print "Single quote found: $2\n";
    } elsif (defined $3) {
        print "Comment found: $3\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
# this is a comment, should be matched.
# "I am not a string" . 'because I am inside a comment'
my $string = " #I am not a comment, because I am quoted";
my $another_string = "I am a multiline string with # on 
                      each line #, have fun!";
```

**Update**

Because you've shown your work and come up with your own solution, I will reveal 3 regular expressions that will match most cases of single and double quoted strings and comments.

```
my $dquo_re = qr{"(?:(?>[^"\\]+)|\\.)*"};
my $squo_re = qr{'(?:(?>[^'\\]+)|\\.)*'};
my $comment_re = qr{(?<!\$)#.*};
```

Outputs:

```
Comment found: # this is a comment, should be matched.
Comment found: # "I am not a string" . 'because I am inside a comment'
Double quote found: " #I am not a comment, because I am quoted"
Double quote found: "I am a multiline string with # on
                      each line #, have fun!"
```

Btw, the most complete way of doing this is using [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PPI;

my $src = do {local $/; <DATA>};

# Load a document
my $doc = PPI::Document->new( \$src );

my $matches = $doc->find(sub{
    grep {$_[1]->isa("PPI::Token::$_")} qw(Comment Quote)
});

for (@$matches) {
    if ($_->isa('PPI::Token::Comment')) {
        print "Comment: ", $_->content;
    } elsif ($_->isa('PPI::Token::Quote')) {
        print "Quote: ", $_->content, "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
# this is a comment, should be matched.
# "I am not a string" . 'because I am inside a comment'
my $string = " #I am not a comment, because I am quoted";
my $another_string = "I am a multiline string with # on 
                      each line #, have fun!";
```

Comment: sorry forgot to say strings and comments need to be captured and HTML style tag will be added to highlight them later.

Comment: @miller what about a cup of tea and some scones ?

Comment: @Tuga I ate em already.  Got some toast if you'd like though.  ;)

Comment: I'm going for bf now, tks anyway :)

Comment: @Miller Sorry, it did not give me the result I wanted. I solved the problem with normal scripting using `index` and `substr` function. Your help still very much appreciated.

Comment: @AskandLearn I've expanded my answer because you've shown your work.  The above solutions should work for most of your cases.

Comment: For the scope of this assignment, PPI is not allowed but I will certainly use it in any other situation.

Answer (score 1):

I finally realized that this maybe too hard if not impossible with regex so I started looking into normal scripting.

It turned out pretty easy with `index` and `substr` function.

This is 3rd version of my code, thanks to Miller pointed out few bugs.

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $src = do {local $/; <DATA>};

my @strings = ();
my @comments = ();
my $off_set = 0;
my $end_index = 0;

while (my ($char, $start_index) = &next_char($off_set)) {
  last if ($char eq "" && $start_index == -1);

  if ($char eq '#') {
    &capture_comment($start_index);
  } elsif (($char eq '"') || ($char eq "'")) {
    &capture_string($char, $start_index, $end_index);
  }
}

print "[Strings]\n";
foreach my $item (@strings) {
  print "$item\n";
}

print "[Comments]\n";
foreach my $item (@comments) {
  print "$item";
}

sub capture_comment($) {
  my $start_index = shift;
  my $char_before = substr $src, $start_index-1, 1;
  # print "\$char_before before # is $char_before\n";
  if ((substr $src, $start_index-1, 1) ne "\$") {
    $end_index = index $src, "\n", $start_index + 1;
    push @comments, substr($src, $start_index, $end_index-$start_index+1);
    $off_set = $end_index + 1;
  } else {
    $off_set = $start_index + 1;
    # print "Array index variable found\n";
  }
}

sub capture_string($ $ $) {
  my $quote = shift;
  my $start_index = shift;
  my $end_index = shift;

  $end_index = index ($src, $quote, $start_index+1);

  CHECK_BACKSLASH:
  my $char_before = substr $src, $end_index-1, 1;
  # print "\$char_before is $char_before\n";

  if ($char_before eq '\\') {
    # print "There is a \\ before $quote\n";
    # print "end index before checking backslash $end_index \n";

    if (&odd_number_backslash($char_before, $start_index, $end_index) == 1) {
      # print "end index after checking backslash $end_index \n";
      $end_index = index $src, $quote, $end_index + 1;
      # print "end index after checking backslash and another index $end_index \n";
      goto CHECK_BACKSLASH;
    }
  }

  push @strings, substr($src, $start_index, $end_index-$start_index+1);
  $off_set = $end_index + 1;
}

sub odd_number_backslash($ $ $) {
  my $char_before = shift;
  my $start_index = shift;
  my $end_index = shift;
  my $count = 0;

  if ($char_before eq '\\') {
    my $ts = substr $src, $start_index, $end_index-$start_index;
    # print "\$ts is $ts\n";
    while ($count <= length $ts) {
      if (chop $ts eq '\\') {
        $count++;
      } else {
        last;
      }
    }
    # print "\$count is $count\n";
    return ($count % 2);
  } else {
    # print "else \$count is $count\n";
    return 1;
  }
}

sub next_char {
  my %has;
  my $position = shift;

  my $s_index = index $src, "'", $position;
  my $d_index = index $src, '"', $position;
  my $c_index = index $src, '#', $position;

  return ("", -1) if ($s_index == -1 &&
                      $d_index == -1 &&
                      $c_index == -1);

  $has{$s_index} = "'" if ($s_index >= 0);
  $has{$d_index} = '"' if ($d_index >= 0);
  $has{$c_index} = '#' if ($c_index >= 0);

  my @sorted_keys = sort { $a <=> $b} keys %has;
  # print "Next char is $has{$sorted_keys[0]}, and position is $sorted_keys[0]\n";
  return ($has{$sorted_keys[0]}, $sorted_keys[0]);
}

__DATA__
my $string = "this is a \" string";
my $windows_path = "C:\\somewhere\\not\\important\\"; # and a comment " yep
# this is a comment, should be matched.
# # "I am not a string" . 'because I am inside a comment'
my $string = " #I am not a comment, because I am quoted";
my $another_string = "I am a multiline string with # on
                      each line #, have fun!";
my @list = (0..99);
print $#list;
my $descap_string = "I am a \ escaped \" \"string"; # and some comments after double;
my $sescap_string = 'I am a \ escaped \' \'string'; # and some comments after single;
my $sescap_string = 'I am a \ escaped \' \'\'\'\'\\'; # and some ' comments by Miller;
my $windows_path = "C:\\somewhere\\not\\important\\"; # and a comment ", yep
    my @array = (1..12);
my $empty_d ="";
my $empty_s ='';
```

And the output

```
[Strings]
"this is a \" string"
"C:\\somewhere\\not\\important\\"
" #I am not a comment, because I am quoted"
"I am a multiline string with # on
                      each line #, have fun!"
"I am a \ escaped \" \"string"
'I am a \ escaped \' \'string'
'I am a \ escaped \' \'\'\'\'\\'
"C:\\somewhere\\not\\important\\"
""
''
[Comments]
# and a comment " yep
# this is a comment, should be matched.
# # "I am not a string" . 'because I am inside a comment'
# and some comments after double;
# and some comments after single;
# and some ' comments by Miller;
# and a comment ", yep
```

Comment: Nice work coming up with your own solution.  Please note that the following will fail: `my $final_string = "I include a \" quote"; # and a comment "`

Comment: Yes, realized that about 30 minutes after I posted it, but I am already in bed. Need to fix that for backslash escaped single quoted string as as well.

Comment: Nice work, ready for another two exception?  What about when a backslash escapes itself?  Also, what about the array index `$#array`.  I will add these two exceptions to your answer here.

Comment: The backslash is a problem, as your script current says the following is a string: `"C:\\somewhere\\not\\important\\"; # and a comment "`  The string should end at the second double quote, and then have a comment.

Comment: `$#array` as the last index of an array is documented here: [`perlintro #Perl variable types`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types).  Also, I found a 3rd bug.  If your data section does not end with a return, the script will just hang.

Comment: Sorry I did not see your code updated till now, will work on it. I do have a deadline for this and I may have to submit the code before all bugs fixed but I will fix them and update my post. This is fun.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50932/discussion-between-ask-and-learn-and-miller)

Comment: I believe I fixed the even number of `backslash` in front of quotes, sorry for the delay, we just came back from holiday. I will start working on `$#array` and update my code once that is fixed also.

Comment: Array index variable `$#array` won't be matched as comment now.