# Strange Perl code bug, exit on 0

Tags: perl

I am writing a Perl code, using `substr` to extract characters one by one but encountered a very strange problem.

I am trying to do the following
Scan character one by one, if it is `#` go to end of line, if it is `'` or `"` then find the next matching one.  Also added HTML color tag to highlight them. Everything else just print.

Here is the block of code

```
while ($char = (substr $src, $off_set, 1)) {

  if ($char eq '#') {
    $end_index = index $src, "\n", $off_set+ 1;
    my $c = substr($src, $off_set, $end_index-$off_set+1);
    print $comment_color.$c.$color_end;
  } elsif (($char eq '"') || ($char eq "'")) {
    $end_index = index ($src, $char, $off_set+1);
    my $char_before = substr $src, $end_index-1, 1;

    while ($end_index > 0 && $char_before eq '\\') {
      $end_index = index $src, $char, $end_index + 1;
      $char_before = substr $src, $end_index-1, 1;
    }
    my $s = substr($src, $off_set, $end_index-$off_set+1);
    print $string_color.$s.$color_end;
  } else {
    print $char;
    $end_index++;
  }
    $off_set = $end_index + 1;
}
```

When I use the following testing code, the script will just exit on first `0`, if I remove  all the `0` then it runs ok. If I remove first `0`, it will exit on 2nd. I really have no idea why this happens.

```
# Comment 1

my $zero = 0;
my @array = (0xdead_beef, 0377, 0b011011);
# xor
sub sample2
{
  print "true or false";
  return 3 + 4 eq " 7"; # true or false
}
   #now write input to STDOUT
print $time . "\n";
my $four = "4";
```

Comment: This is a pretty stupid, I had problem with `while (chop)` before as well, now I knew it is the same reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) in your [`while`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/while.html) loop:

```
while (defined(my $char = substr $src, $off_set, 1)) {
```

The reason why your code was exiting early is because `'0'` is a false value, and therefore the `while` would end.  Instead, this will check if any value is pulled from the `substr` call.

Comment: You still online ? Can I chat with you?

Answer (score 3):

This is your loop condition:

```
while ($char = (substr $src, $off_set, 1)) {
    ...
```

So what happens when `$char = "0"`? As Perl considers that to be a false value, the loop will terminate. Instead, loop as long as characters are left:

```
while ($off_set < length $src) {
    my $char = substr $src, $off_set, 1;
    ...
```

Anyway, your code is convoluted and hard to read. Consider using regular expressions instead:

```
use re '/xsm';

my $src = ...;
pos($src) = 0;
my $out = '';
while (pos($src) < length $src) {
    if ($src =~ m/\G ([#][^\n]*)/gc) {
        $out .= colored(comment => $1);
    }
    elsif ($src =~ m/\G (["] (?:[^"\\]++|[\\].)* ["])/gc) {
        $out .= colored(string => $1);
    }
    elsif ($src =~ m/\G (['] (?:[^'\\]++|[\\]['\\])* ['])/gc) {
        $out .= colored(string => $1);
    }
    elsif ($src =~ m/\G ([^"'#]+)/gc) {
        $out .= $1;
    }
    else {
        die "illegal state";
    }
}
```

where `colored` is some helper function.

Comment: I have a problem to match `comment` and `string`. Because quoted chars not `string` if them in `comment`, and `#` may appear in `strings`. Yes it is hard to read, working on it.

Comment: Don't think I can use `xsm` unless it is a standarded Perl module. I tried `perl -Mre::xsm` and it failed. Is that the correct way to test if a module is installed ?

Comment: @AskandLearn My example regex-based parser handles quotes in strings correctly and hash marks in strings correctly – the whole point of this `m//gc` style parsing is that the internal `pos()` of the string is advanced correctly. How this works exactly is a bit too complicated to explain in a comment. The `use re '/xsm'` loads the `re` module which is in the Perl Core, and makes all regexes have the flags `/xsm` activated by default. The command-line equivalent is `-Mre=/xsm`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, figured out it is the while loop. It exit the loop when it sees a `0`.

Updated the `while` loop condition to

```
while (($char = (substr $src, $off_set, 1)) || ($off_set < (length $src))) {
```

and it is working now.

Comment: Note, it's sufficient to just check the `$offset` value in the `while` loop condition.  I'd consider moving the `substr` call to the first line within the `while` block.

Comment: Yes, already did that. I still believe that I am doing the hard way to find comments and strings but I could not get a working regex. I don't have enough knowledge to say that is impossible. What do you think ? based on my requirements, is there a single regex can do that for me ?

Comment: Of course there is.  I already showed you one in [the previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23100637/1733163)